# How to convert a 2D numpy array to an tensorflow array for image prediction

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Is there an easy way to convert a 2D numpy array to a tf array for image prediction? Currently I have a greyscale image that I have to import into python using another API which gives me a 2D numpy array of pixel values. I then have to save this array as an image and reimport the image in tensorflow so I basically end up with the following:

```
npArray = np.random.rand(100,100)

plt.imsave('image.png', npArray, cmap='Greys')

imgTf = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
        'image.png', target_size=(100, 100)
    )

imgTfArray = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(imgTf)
imgTfArrayBatch = tf.expand_dims(imgTfArray, 0)  # Create a batch
```

This then continues on to feed the image to a trained model and return a prediction.

ideally I want to just be able to feed the npArray in rather than having to save a file and open a file but the numpy array is 2D whilst the opened image is a 3D array. Is there a way to easily convert?

Comment: tf.keras.Model.predict accepts numpy array as an input as you an see it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Comment: @delirium78 for reasons of deployment I am using tf-lite for these bits which doesn't appear to use model.predict and instead use interpreter.get_signature_runner('serving_default') and pass the image through that.

Comment: `npArray = np.random.rand(100, 100, 1)` and all of a sudden you have three channels... Or add an axis via `npArray[:, :, np.newaxis]`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is tensorflow wants an RGB image so you have to fake it when using greyscale. The solution is to stack the array 3 times to represent the 3 RGB channels.

```
npArray = np.stack([npArray, npArray, npArray], axis=2)
```

Once you have done this you can feed it through

```
imgArray = tf.expand_dims(npArray.astype(dtype='float32'), 0)  # Create a batch
```

Then feed it into a tf lite classification and it should all work fine.